# курс али по апи

Tags: python, pandas

есть телеграмм бот, которые успешно получается курсы валют, но с курсам алиэкспресса вышла загвоздка,
пробовала через библиотеку request то есть сохраняла всю страницу сайта в текст, а потом оттуда методом поиска и индексации вытаскивала данные, сейчас данный сайт перестал существовать.
Нашла сайт, в котором курс представлен табличным методом.
Пробую через библиотеку pandas но из 10 запросов - где-то 4 это ошибка keyerror, то есть 6 раз курс парсится и все ок, а потом может 4 раза подряд вылететь ошибка, что ключа нет, а потом снова работает . код самый простой

```
tables = pd.read_html('https://helpix.ru/currency/')
print(tables[0]['Aliexpress.com'][0])
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. [См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Понять бы ещё - за что так яростно минусуют вопрос? На мой взгляд тут только импорты бы ещё добавить. Ну и трейс ошибки полностью в вопросе привести.

Comment: @CrazyElf возможно, не знали, что вы ответите :)) а серьезно - это как и оценки ответов, никакой логике порой не подвержены

Comment: @splash58 Да я понимаю, но вдруг кто признается - в чём таки логика. Use case вроде бы достаточно подробно описан, мне его для ответа вполне хватило )

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, там иногда `Pandas` принимает за таблицу какой-то скрипт на странице и поэтому нумерация таблиц съезжает, поэтому нужная вам таблица становится уже не с индексом `0`, а с индексом `1`. Можно (и даже нужно) проверять, в какой именно из найденных таблиц есть нужный столбец с данными и обращаться уже дальше к этой таблице:

```py
for df in tables:
    if 'Aliexpress.com' in df.columns:
        print(df.loc[0, 'Aliexpress.com'])

# 81.26
```

Comment: спасибо большое, не знаю даже, почему сама  не додумалась до проверки. Все работает)

Comment: Тогда отметьте мой ответ как подходящий, там специальная галочка должна быть )